# EXPLAIN SELECT LIKE

Tags: mysql

I will show you what I am trying to achieve before going into detail

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM db.xxx WHERE xxx.information LIKE '%incorrectInformation%';
```

Basically, I have imported data from one database and structure to another, and unfortunately there has been some unicode errors I just want to replace "incorrectInformation" with a different string, for example "correctInformation".

I want to know how many fields it is going to return so I can know what the best sort of limit to put on it would be.

The table I am dealing with has 8 billion entries, so I dont really want to run it unlimited, and doing it with a limit of like 10 is taking a few seconds to execute.

Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

The actual query I will be running is something like this:

```
UPDATE db.xxx SET information = REPLACE(information, 'incorrectInformation', 'correctInformation') where information LIKE '%incorrectInformation%' LIMIT 10;
```

The reason I want the explain to work, is if theres only 100 fields that need to be updated, I dont mind doing the limit 10, 10 times. However, if its like a few hundred thousand, which I highly suspect then I need a much better solution.

Any help you can provide is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, EXPLAIN is only going to tell you how much work it has to do, not necessarily how many rows will be in the result.

What you could do is select the primary keys for the problem rows into a temporary table, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (PRIMARY KEY(id))
SELECT id FROM xxx WHERE yyy LIKE '%whatever%';
```

That might take a while, but you can then use your temporary table to further examine the scope of the problem, and also use it to perform the processing quicker when you're ready.

```
UPDATE xxx,foo SET xxx.yyy='woo yay' WHERE xxx.id=foo.id;
```

And when you're done, just `DROP TABLE foo;`